# Dynamics CRM Record not Showning in OrganizationData EntitySet

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have created a record in a custom entity with a plug-in.
The record shows in the view for the entity,
but not in XRMServices entity set! 
There are many other records in the set that I can view from

```
OrganizationData.svc/{!entitylogicalname}Set
```

Why would records be visible in the view for active records, but not in the entity set?

The entity has no custom fields and was created with

```
IOrganizationService.Create({early_bound_entity});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that only 50 records are shown? This is default maximum number of records for retrieving with OData query. You can increase this number (check this [two](https://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/03/16/how-to-increase-the-50-record-page-limit-on-odata-retrieve-responses-for-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx) [links](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crminthefield/archive/2012/03/16/how-to-increase-the-50-record-page-limit-on-odata-retrieve-responses-for-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx)).

If you are using SDK.REST.js, method RetrieveMultipleRecords will handle this.

Hope this helps :)